# How can i create just one instance of HostListener while it is used in multiply instances of same directive

Tags: angular

I am having directive.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoCompletion]',
  exportAs: 'autoCompletion'
})
export class AutoCompleteDirective {
 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target']) onDocumentClick(targetElement) {
    if (targetElement.id !== this.autoCompleteSearchInput) {
        this.p.closeDropDown();
    }
  }

}
```

inside it i am listening whenever is clicked outside of the input - the dropdown should be closed.

The problem is that multiply directives are created -

for example:

```
 <input autoCompletion/>
 <input autoCompletion/>
 <input autoCompletion/>
 <input autoCompletion/>
 <input autoCompletion/>
```

this means that when i click on the HTML document, five times is called the method - onDocumentClick.

How can i prevent this from happening ?

I googled and i did not found some solution for this

Answer (score 0):

So to understand your question correctly. You have an input in a ngFor loop and u have the directive inside the loop which causes to generate multiple host listeners. When you instantiate the directive the host listeners get registered. Since you instantiate the directive four times it gets registered four. So you should move your hostlistener to your component where the inputs are added and then control it by the input id than having it inside a hostlistener

So do u need this host listener at all?
Cant you use:

```
<input (focus)="dropDown=true;" (blur)="dropDown=false;" />
<div *ngIf="dropDown">
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I understood from you question. You wanted the drop down to close when u remove the focus from you input. So isnt it better to use a blur than have a document click hostlistener?

Comment: I needed hostListener because i needed to close ALL opened inputs, with onBlur i will close just the last opened one

Comment: So having a hostlistener thats listens for a document.click whenever u instantiate a directive will drastically affect you performance of your application. If u want a Singleton then its better to add a window listener to the or a document listener inside a service using addEventlistener. However, it’s only recommended to set event listeners on window or document if you are sure that the directive will be used only once or very few times across the application. Having many directives that listen to the same event on the global elements could eventually hurt the performance of your application.

Comment: Adding the HostListener to the component where you are adding the input will be the best way if u really want to use a Hostlistener. So that when the component is destroyed the host listener is destroyed and you wont have multiple instantiations of HostListeners

Comment: I know that - but i am building library, i wanted to make this things out of the box, when some user installs my library as npm package. Otherwise he will need to manually add this hostListener and that is not a good way for making the libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can control the document onclick outside the directive

If in your component you get yours AutoCompleteDirective  using viewChildren and control using fromEvent

```
@ViewChildren(AutoCompleteDirective)autocompletes:QueryList<AutoCompleteDirective>

ngOnInit()
{
   formEvent(document,'click').subscribe(event=>{
       this.autocompletes.forEach(x=>{
         if (event.targetElement.id !== x.autoCompleteSearchInput) {
              x.p.closeDropDown();
         } 
       })
   })
}
```

I imagine that another option is create a new directive that mannage the document click event (but I'm not prety sure about it)

```
@Directive({
 selector: 'formAutocompletion'
})
export class FormAutoCompletionDirective {
 click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(shareReplay(1))
}
```

Now your directive can ask about it

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoCompletion]',
  exportAs: 'autoCompletion'
})
export class AutoCompleteDirective {
  click$: Observable<Event>;

  constructor(@Optional() @Host() private form: FormAutoCompletionDirective)
  {
    this.click$ = this.form ? this.form.click$ : null
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    if (this.click$){
      this.click$.subscribe((event)=>{
        if (event.targetElement.id !== this.autoCompleteSearchInput) {
          this.p.closeDropDown();
      }
    }
  }
```

And you write

```
<form formAutoComplete>
   <input autoCompletion/>
   <input autoCompletion/>
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: but i am building library, i wanted to make this things out of the box, when some user installs my library as npm package. Otherwise he will need to manually add this formEvent RXJS LISTENER and that is not a good way for making the libraries